# Insert data into an exact copy of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases.. exact same structures and "nearly" all of it is duplicate data.However I have updated records in database1 that need to go in database2. Now is there an easy way to push all of the new data from database1 to database2 without getting the duplicate records as well?

NOTE I do not know how many\which tables have updated data in them.

EDIT: There are no "modified" rows of data just "new" rows of data

Comment: Truncate the existing tables, push everything?

Comment: Define "new data", does modifications to existing rows count?

Comment: have you tried merge?

Comment: Does every table have a primary key to uniquely identify rows, and therefore allow you identify differences in rows? The easiest way really is 'brute force' where you simply delete and reload all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great breadth of options.

If the value of your tables' primary keys does not need updating, I might suggest [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'Old', '2014-08-20 18:47:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | data | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | Old  | 2014-08-20 18:47:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then:

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'New', '2014-08-20 18:47:42');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | data | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | New  | 2014-08-20 18:47:42 |
+----+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

# (Example Straight from the MySQL AB)
```

You can wrap that entire operation in a [`TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

**After OP edit**: You can still use this as `REPLACE INTO` will just `INSERT INTO` if it doesn't find a candidate row with matching primary keys to update.

To do this streaming mysqldump, you could:

```
mysqldump --replace --no-create-info database1 | mysql database2
```

Or a simpler `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE IGNORE` since you don't actually need to update rows:

```
mysqldump --insert-ignore --no-create-info database1 | mysql database2
```

Comment: he's using mssql

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication

Microsoft SQL Server provides the following types of replication for use in distributed applications:

- Transactional replication. For more information, see Transactional
  Replication.
- Merge replication. For more information, see Merge    Replication.
- Snapshot replication. For more information, see Snapshot
  Replication.

The type of replication you choose for an application depends on many factors, including the physical replication environment, the type and quantity of data to be replicated, and whether the data is updated at the Subscriber. The physical environment includes the number and location of computers involved in replication and whether these computers are clients (workstations, laptops, or handheld devices) or servers.

Each type of replication typically begins with an initial synchronization of the published objects between the Publisher and Subscribers. This initial synchronization can be performed by replication with a snapshot, which is a copy of all of the objects and data specified by a publication. After the snapshot is created, it is delivered to the Subscribers. For some applications, snapshot replication is all that is required. For other types of applications, it is important that subsequent data changes flow to the Subscriber incrementally over time. Some applications also require that changes flow from the Subscriber back to the Publisher. Transactional replication and merge replication provide options for these types of applications.

Data changes are not tracked for snapshot replication; each time a snapshot is applied, it completely overwrites the existing data. Transactional replication tracks changes through the SQL Server transaction log, and merge replication tracks changes through triggers and metadata tables.

Some tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-tutorials